# Is there performance loss if I install software on secondary SSD

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, performance

As far as the facts go, software installed on SSD load/work many times faster than on mechanical drives.

As far as I've heard the myth you want to install the most important stuff on the Boot drive, due to the way Microsoft works and access files and etc (that's probably not true, its just what I've heard).

Will I ever notice any performance difference between a program or game running from my boot SSD C:\ drive, compared to a regular non-boot SSD D:\ drive ?

Comment: The difference if any will be due to different speeds of the different drives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If any impact the load times should be faster if installed on a secondary drive. This assumption is due to the fact that Windows can do it's read/write thing on drive c:, while the app loads (in parallel) from d:. I have no stats, but i have been using a secondary drive for many years and try to split Windows Operating System and apps+data on a second drive. Overall my Laptop has been much more usable for many more years - compared to those of colleges.